# How to prevent duplicate sum after lookup and unwind mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sum, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection torder(set of sales,customers,subtotals and invoices)  and tsales (set of sales info, it has 1 or more contacts), then I want to check how many total orders of each customer during current period, here my code before I put $unwind :

```
db.torder.aggregate([
        {$match:{$and:[{TANGGALPI:{$gte:'2019-01-01'}},{TANGGALPI:{$lte:'2019-12-31'}}]}},
        {$lookup:{
                from:"tsales",
                localField:"IDSALES",
                foreignField:"SALESCODE",
                as:"SALESINFO"
        }},
        {$group:{
                _id:"$CUSTNAME",SALES:{$first:"$SALESINFO.NAMASALES"},TOTAL : { $sum: {$multiply:["$QTY","$PRICE"]}}}},
        {$sort:{TOTAL:-1}}
])
```

and it will return output like this :

```
[{"_id":"CUSTOMER ABC","SALES":(Array) 2 Elements,"TOTAL":231986}]
```

Then I do $unwind, change array element to field element :

```
db.torder.aggregate([
        {$match:{$and:[{TANGGALPI:{$gte:'2019-01-01'}},{TANGGALPI:{$lte:'2019-12-31'}}]}},
        {$lookup:{
                from:"tsales",
                localField:"IDSALES",
                foreignField:"SALESCODE",
                as:"SALESINFO"
        }},
        {$unwind : "$SALESINFO"},
        {$group:{
                _id:"$CUSTNAME",SALES:{$first:"$SALESINFO.NAMASALES"},TOTAL : { $sum: {$multiply:["$QTY","$PRICE"]}}}},
        {$sort:{TOTAL:-1}}
])
```

its output become :

```
[{"_id":"CUSTOMER ABC","SALES":"Peter","TOTAL":463972}] => total will become 2 times than before
```

I check in my tsales collection, Sales Peter has two rows values so make duplicates sum value, how to do make correct calculation sum with single row of tsales collection with $unwind

I want output like this :

```
[{"_id":"CUSTOMER ABC","SALES":"Peter","TOTAL":231986}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to swap [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage.

```
db.torder.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "TANGGALPI": { "$gte": "2019-01-01", "$lte": "2019-12-31" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$CUSTNAME",
    "IDSALES": { "$first": "$IDSALES" },
    "TOTAL": { "$sum": { "$multiply": ["$QTY", "$PRICE"] } },
    "duplicateNames": { "$push": "$name" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "tsales",
    "localField": "IDSALES",
    "foreignField": "SALESCODE",
    "as": "SALES"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "SALES": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$SALES.NAMASALES", 0] }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "TOTAL": -1 } }
])
```